# Copy an attribute from one element to another

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, label

I have a several columns of :checkboxes and labels.

```
<ul class="column1">
    <li>
        <input value="jan" type="checkbox" />
        <label>Jan</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="feb" type="checkbox" />
        <label>Feb</label>
    </li>
    <li> etc..<li>
</ul>
```

I have copied the val from the attribute value"" to the attribute id""

```
var tagCheckbox = ("ul li :checkbox");

$(tagCheckbox).attr("id", function() { 
    return "id_" + this.value;       
});
```

Now I want to copy the val of the input value"" or id"" to the attribute for"" on the  `<label>`

**How can I do that?**

*.attr(,); wont do it alone, because it only grabs the first :checkbox and copy that same value to all labels*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(tagCheckbox).attr("id", function() { 
    var val="id_" + this.value;
    $(this).next('label').attr('for',val);
    return val;       
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! and yet so simple. Thank you